# Can't access my site due to fatal error

Tags: fatal-error, warnings

I tried to access my site after a months break and can't even get the admin page to login. site is www.puncturecallout.com
seems to mention the paypal plugin as the problem? Will be painfully simply to some i apologise, layman's terms would be appreciated. Site not backed up computer so no idea how to access it.
thanks
robbie

Comment: Do you try to disable the plugin via database?

Answer (score 1):

The "White Screen of Death" (which I assume is your issue, since you provided minimal details) can usually be diagnosed starting with the error.log file for you site.

This is available via your hosting Control Panel, File Manager, or via FTP access.

The latest error will usually show a folder/file that is causing the problem. If it is in the 'plugins' folder (like wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/something.php), then rename the 'plugin-name' to something else (again, via your hosting File Manager or FTP). (You don't need to disable the plugin via the database; renaming the bad plugin's folder will disable it.)

Then, try to get to the site, and log in as an admin. Install all updates (look in Dashboard, Updates after admin login) and continue from there.

Lots of answers if you do ask the googles for "WordPress White Screen of Death". But the above should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I didn't know that it is so easy to deactivate a plugin by changing the the folder name. thx :)

Comment: Yep...standard troubleshooting when you get a 'white screen of death' or fatal errors is to assume that a plugin is at fault. So renaming the plugin's folder effectively disables the plugin that is (probably) causing the problem. You can disable all plugins by renaming the wp-content/plugin folder.   (If my answer is correct, use the checkmark to mark it so.)